# Google tag Manager Data Layer Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I want to track click on the highlighted part in image below  and pass data to GA  using dataLayer. [image]

In the image above (please refer highlighted section in the box)  under **"view-content"** class there are  three class with same name "top-pick-item"In each class there is hyper link. I want to track how many time a particular link is click. 
The main concern is that this hyperlink changes frequently and this done by other team without informing the team. Hence I can use the default GTM click url functionality.  I have written the below code for tracking.
  This is for **first** url click
                            jQuery(".view-content").click(function() {

```
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("top-picks-item")) {
        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'url-click',
        'category': 'navigation',
        'action': 'click',
        'label': 'AT1'
     });
```

This is for second url click

```
     jQuery(".view-content").click(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("top-picks-item")) {
        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'url-click',
        'category': 'navigation',
        'action': 'click',
        'label': 'AT2'
     });
```

Above jquery  executes but the problem is that if i click second url the first Jquery execute and not the second one.
 What code should i write so that second Jquery execute on second url click

Answer (score 0):

For your second piece of code, you could use the `nth-child()` selector to target only the second item:

```
jQuery('.view-content .top-picks-item:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
   dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'url-click',
        'category': 'navigation',
        'action': 'click',
        'label': 'AT2'
   })
})
```

The ideal approach would be to get your dev, since they're changing the site, to also add in specific IDs to each of those divs, so that you can easily differentiate the first, second, or third, or n'th div.